# MINA: Is finishDecode where I send a response message?

Tags: java, sockets, nio, apache-mina

In using Apache MINA, I'm sending a login request from the client, which is interpreted on the server via `LoginRequestDecoder (implements org.apache.mina.filter.codec.demux.MessageDecoder)`.

I now want to send a response (`LoginResponse`) that includes a success/failure code.  Should I be sending the response from the `LoginRequestDecoder's` `finishDecode()` method, or is there a better place for it that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was make my [IoHandler](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/core/service/IoHandler.html) of type [DemuxingIoHandler](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/handler/demux/DemuxingIoHandler.html). Within its constructuor, I had to make multiple calls to `addReceivedMessageHandler` and `addSentMessageHandler`.  This allows the code behind DemuxingIoHandler to automatically respond based upon the type of message received.